# Issue on Assigning Value Global Variable in jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jquery-ajaxq

I have a script and jQuery Ajax call like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var timer;
  $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
         url: 'closettime.php',
         success: function( res ){
         var json = JSON.parse(res);
             timer = json["datecounter"];
             alert(timer);
         }
    });   
 var date = new Date(timer);
 var now   = new Date();                
 var diff  = date.getTime()/1000 - now.getTime()/1000;
 var clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(diff, {
    clockFace: 'HourlyCounter',
    countdown: true,
    showSeconds: true
 });

});
</script>
```

now my problem is I am not able to assign the time value in `var date = new Date(timer);` in ajax success callback as

```
timer = json["datecounter"];
```

can you please let me know how to fix this? thanks

Comment: Could you `console.log(json);` and `console.log(json["datecounter"]);`  and let us know what you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is likely that the request does not finish completing until after the code to assign your date variable completes, so there is the illusion that timer is not being assigned. Move all of your code that depends on the timer variable into the callback and this should work, or at least fix one of the issues.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'closettime.php',
       success: function( res ){
           var json = JSON.parse(res);
           var timer = json["datecounter"];
           alert(timer);
           var date = new Date(timer);
           var now   = new Date();                
           var diff  = date.getTime()/1000 - now.getTime()/1000;
           var clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(diff, {
              clockFace: 'HourlyCounter',
              countdown: true,
              showSeconds: true
           });
       }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Nile, thanks for reply but is there any way to keep the second part of the code out of the success function like what i was trying to do and get the same result back?

Comment: As a suggestion, use deferred.done instead of XHR.success - see "Deprecation Notice" on http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/.  Using the promise methods will insure your code works in future versions of jquery and makes for lest curly nesting.

Comment: @Suffii Since it is async, code after your ajax call is going to run regardless of whether or not the success function has run yet, maybe try setting `async: false` in your call? Never used that but I've seen it used before.